# Fixing null warnings on data returned after a database call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ado.net

I have been away from C# programming for a couple of years due to other work commitments and trying to ease back into the thick of things again.

Last time I coded the following code was allowed, and didn't give me any warnings:

```
public async Task<User> GetAsync(string userId)
{
    User user = null;
    using (SqlConnection connection = sqlObjectFactory.GetConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = sqlObjectFactory.GetCommand("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Users WHERE UserId = '12345678';", connection))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            using SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            if (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                user = new User
                {
                    FirstName = reader.GetString("FirstName"),
                    LastName = reader.GetString("LastName")
                };
            }
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```

However there are warnings on the following lines of code:

```
User user = null;

Warning: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
```

And..

```
return user;

Warning: Possible null reference return.
```

I'm not really sure how to fix these warnings? I mean there can only be 2 possible values returned, either the user is found then return the user's details, or if no user is found then return nothing/null back.

What is best practices here? Please can you guys advise?

I know a lot of the code can be simplified but lets not focus on that, I just quickly put something together for the sake of the post. I also know you can turn the warnings off but I like them so I don't want to turn them off.

I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Basically you should read up on the Nullable Reference Types feature, introduced in C# 8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference types (such as your User object) have become non-nullable by default (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). That means they cannot contain a null value anymore without explicitly declaring them as nullable.

What you could do is return User? from your function (notice the question mark). Adding a question mark means the variable can be null. It might be appropriate to rename your function to TryGetAsync to let the caller know about the null allowance.